# Extendability of isometries of convex surfaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $K$ be a 3-dimensional convex compact subset either in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or in the 3-dimensional real hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^3$. Consider its boundary $\partial K$ equipped with the inner (path) metric induced from the ambient space.

> Is it true that any isometric map $T\colon \partial K\to \partial K$ is a restriction of an isometry of the ambient space ($\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{H}^3$)?

If it matters, I am particularly interested in the case when $T$ is an isometric involution without fixed points.

A reference would be very helpful.

Comment: If the answer is yes, there is some subtle reason, because it's obviously false in dimension 2 (the boundary with its path metric has many self-isometries, but they don't all extend unless $K$ is a disc).

Comment: You are right. The case of convex surfaces in 3-space is very special. I do not ask  what happens in higher dimension, though still would be curious to know.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. It follows from the Cohn-Vossen rigidity theorem. This is stated and proved starting on page 86 of http://www.math.brown.edu/~deigen/chern.pdf.

Comment: In higher dimensions the result is easy to prove when the second fundamental form is positive definite. That's because at a point where the second fundamental form is positive definite, the Riemann curvature tensor uniquely determines the second fundamental form.

Comment: If the boundary of $K$ is smooth, then, as Deane Yang points out, this is the Cohn-Vossen rigidity theorem. The same is true without the smoothness assumption, which is the Pogorelov rigidity theorem (with a notoriously complicated proof).

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev Could you please state precisely the Pogorelov theorem. A reference would be very helpful. Also if you explain how it implies my question, it would be the final answer. Thank you.

Comment: I believe that Pogorelov proved it in complete generality. Any two isometric convex surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ differ by a rigid motion. It’s in his book https://books.google.com/books/about/Extrinsic_Geometry_of_Convex_Surfaces.html?id=PI4mo2yX8HoC

Comment: However I know of no equivalent theorem in complete generality for a convex surface in hyperbolic space.

Comment: @DeaneYang Is the Cohn-Vossen theorem true in hyperbolic space?